# Is accepting a request without a Referer evidence of CSRF?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, csrf, fiddler

I use Fiddler to look at some attack-vectors on my site. 
I copy the http-request from my validate-function and changed it: I cut off the referer-line. And it works. Is that an evidence for CSRF?

The Question in other Words: When I reproduce the HTTP-Request in Fiddler without the Referer, is that an evidence that my Site is vulnerable against CSRF? Or can I look for CSRF-Attacks by using only Fiddler?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, no. Referer-checking is one way to attempt to prevent CSRF, but it's generally not the best choice because some intermediaries strip this header, and if the client  browser or one of its plugins had a bug, an attacker could send a fake referer. Most sites today send a *nonce* in the HTTP POST body that the server uses to validate that the request was generated by a page on the 1st party site and not a cross-site request.

Comment: +1. Secret tokens are the accepted solution to CSRF; referrer-checking is a weak and fragile approach which should only be used as a temporary workaround until a vulnerable application is fixed properly.